# What is the meaning of JSP Verbatim?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am reading JSP & Servlet from Head First. In it's mock exam, here is the following example given :-

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="true" %>
<%A taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<c:set var="awesomeBand" value="LIMOZEEN"/>
${awesomeBand}
```

Options to choose are :-

1. ${awesomeBand}
2. LIMOZEEN
3. No Output
4. An exception will be thrown because all taglib directives must precede any page directives

The correct answer given is A. The explanation given is the EL Expression is ignored and passed through verbatim. I tried searching for this term but it leads me to jsf verbatim. I am unable to understand what does verbatim means? Can someone help understanding this concept?

Thanks

Comment: is there `A` is present in `<%A taglib..` in real question?

Answer (score 0):

In this case verbatim means "word for word" (see [here](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/verbatim)).

In the example, the text `${awesomeBand}` is not interpreted by the container and the resulting page contains the same text.